# As a Terran, how can I punish a Protoss if I know he's going 4 gate?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I'm in Gold League and all day I play against 4 Gate Protoss. How can I take advantage of this as soon as I scout it? Obviously, it's hard to take advantage with an expansion against this kind of early aggression, even with bunkers.

Comment: With Terran? or any race?

Comment: @Wipqozn I edited the headline to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Wall in, tech up to siege tanks w/ siege, build a few, and plant them at your base entrance.** Assuming you scout early enough, this method requires the least micro and will allow you a solid transition into an expansion.

You can also try to build up a few bunkers & stock them with marine/marauder. This can be effective as well as long as you keep the ranged Protoss units out of range of your repairing SCVs (a.k.a. walling in).

For either of the above, you'll want to watch out for void rays. That's usually how your 4-gate counter will be countered.

Banshees with cloak can be somewhat effective but the siege tanks have more longevity in terms of utilization for the rest of the match.

Marauders with concussive shells can also be effective if you have the micro for it.

Comment: +1 Siege Tanks are really effective at stopping ground rushes. In fact a wall-in with a few siege tanks can make an early game aggression  pointless

Comment: How are you going to get a helpful amount of siege tanks before 7 minutes? That's even besides the point that you have to target fire stalkers, because if you hit the zealots, you will be killing your own bunkers. You cannot punish a 4 gate. The correct way to win is to bunker up, 3-4, pull scvs to the front of the bunkers and keep pumping marines & scv's (along with a few marauders). Once it ends, you win. This is all asumming you do 1rax FE, which is the standard for Terran if not rushing themselves.

Comment: @jsn We're basically saying the same thing. I'm not saying you should have tons of tanks out by the 7-minute mark, but you want to wall-in to hold it off. If they keep pushing the 4-gate, pumping out M&Ms isn't going to change the situation. You have to tech into a counter so you're not just throwing units against one-another.

Comment: @Shaun siege tech takes way precious gas (and minerals) from medivacs and upgrades that early in the game. Seige tanks are useless in TvP. You are going to have 1 tank out with siege tech only finishing (not finished) by the time 4gate hits. It is not going to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to wrack my brain about how to punish the protoss player, but unless you can stay alive through the push, it would be very difficult to punish them before they come up with an army knocking on your front door.

So assuming you survive with bunkers and marines/marauders/scvs set on repair the ideal tech path would be to go cloaked banshee.

If they are 4gating they cut probe production which means you're already ahead economically. It also means they won't have a robotics bay to build an observer, you are free to pick off as many probes as you have energy, which will give you even more of an economic advantage and you will get the win assuming you continue to macro effectively.